# Select range using specific criteria within a contiguous column of data

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I want to have VBA select a Range, covering a constant number of columns but differing numbers of rows from a contiguous data set in excel, capturing only the rows that contain matching timestamps (in this specific case, although the ability to match any criteria is more dynamic obviously). I want to feed this Range into another macro I have. After my macro has run its process on the captured range, i'd want it to loop through the whole process again using the next captured range in line.

```
      A       B       C           D       E       F
1     x       x       12:10       x       x       x
2     x       x       12:10       x       x       x
3     x       x       12:10       x       x       x
4     x       x       12:40       x       x       x
5     x       x       12:40       x       x       x
6     x       x       12:40       x       x       x
7     x       x       12:40       x       x       x
8     x       x       1:05        x       x       x
9     x       x       1:05        x       x       x
10    x       x       1:05        x       x       x
```

For example,

I'd like to capture columns A-F, rows 1-3 as one Range, run my macro, then...

I'd like to capture columns A-F, rows 4-7 as another Range, run my macro, then...

I'd like to capture columns A-F, rows 8-10 as another Range, run my macro, etc... until there aren't any more ranges below this to capture.

As you can see, the rows in this case are differentiated by their timestamps.

I'm just a couple of days in getting to grips with VBA, I have a basic underatanding of what does what, just not the experience to piece this one together from other examples I've found.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to:

1. Copy your data to an array
2. Inspect the array to find the contiguous ranges (looping this array is much faster than looping the cells)
3. Call your macro with the identified range

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    v = sh.[A1].CurrentRegion ' Assumes data range starts at cell A1
    ' Alternative method to get data block starting at A3
    ' Extend to a specified column number (NumberOfColumnsYouWant)
    ' Assumes all rows in your data block in columns A have data
    v = sh.Range([A3], [A3].End(xlDown)).Resize(, NumberOfColumnsYouWant)


    i = 1
    j = 1
    Do While i <= UBound(v, 1)
        Do While j < UBound(v, 1)
            If v(i, 3) = v(j + 1, 3) Then
                j = j + 1
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        YourMacro Range(sh.Cells(i, 1), sh.Cells(j, UBound(v, 2)))
        i = j + 1
        j = i
    Loop
 End Sub

 Sub YourMacro(rng As Range)
     MsgBox rng.Address
 End Sub
```

Comment: This is great Chris, thanks. Just looking at this helps me learn. It needs a few tweaks though for it to fit my needs perfectly. In my worksheet my data starts at "A3". Also, is there a way to specify the furthest column away from "A" that it captures? The reason is that my data is a set block, and it never deviates. This is clever though, thanks again.

Comment: @Toby Please accept Chris's answer if it works for you by clicking on the check mark link  next to the answer.

Comment: @Toby, I've updated my answer with an alternative way of geting the data block.  Note that `sh.[A3].CurrentRegion` should fullfil your needs anyway

Comment: @Abbas Thanks, I would if it indeed did what I needed it to do. At the moment it's selecting many more columns than is required. This is important as the macro I call later copies the selected data and pastes it elsewhere. The absolute range of the data is critical.

Comment: @Toby new information - there exist more data next to the range of interest: in that case the alternative method would work `v = sh.Range([A3], [A3].End(xlDown)).Resize(, 6)` or even `v = sh[A3].CurrentRegion.Resize(, 6)`

Comment: I have headers in the top two rows. I'd like the macro to ignore these. At the moment the code is, first, capturing those two rows (one at a time), and then it performs as i'd need it to (:D). Even with the stipulation that [A3] be the starting point it ignores this!? Am I missing something (of course I am, duuuurrr!) Also, the last alternative in your comment works nicely.

Comment: Use `v = sh.Range([Ax], [Ax].End(xlDown)).Resize(, 6)` where `Ax` = the first _data_ cell (excluding headers).  In general, use `Range(TopLeftCell, BottomRightCell)` to get a reference to a specified range